# User variables of a function, in another function

Tags: php, laravel, function, variables, laravel-5

I have a Laravel app, which the following PHP code:

```
   public function handle()
    {
                            $post_item->category_id = $source->category_id;
                            $post_item->featured = 0;
                            $post_item->type = Posts::TYPE_SOURCE;
                            $post_item->render_type = $item['render_type'];
                            $post_item->source_id = $source->id;
                            $post_item->description = is_array($item['description'])?'':$item['description'];
                            $post_item->featured_image = $item['featured_image'];
                            $post_item->video_embed_code = $item['video_embed_code'];
                            $post_item->dont_show_author_publisher = $source->dont_show_author_publisher;
                            $post_item->show_post_source = $source->show_post_source;
                            $post_item->show_author_box = $source->dont_show_author_publisher == 1 ? 0 : 1;
                            $post_item->show_author_socials = $source->dont_show_author_publisher == 1 ? 0 : 1;
                            $post_item->rating_box = 0;
                            $post_item->created_at = $item['pubDate'];
                            $post_item->views = 1;
                            $post_item->save();
                            $this->createTags($item['categories'], $post_item->id);

                           // This is where I want to add my echo
   }


   public function createTags($tags, $post_id)
    {

        $post_tags = PostTags::where('post_id', $post_id)->get();

        foreach ($post_tags as $post_tag) {
            Tags::where('id', $post_tag->tag_id)->delete();
        }

        PostTags::where('post_id', $post_id)->delete();

        foreach ($tags as $tag) {

            $old_tag=Tags::where('title',$tag)->first();

            if(isset($old_tag))
            {

                $pt = new PostTags();
                $pt->post_id = $post_id;
                $pt->tag_id = $old_tag->id;
                $pt->save();

            }

            else {
                $new_tag = new Tags();
                $new_tag->title = $tag;
                $new_tag->slug = Str::slug($tag);
                $new_tag->save();

                $pt = new PostTags();
                $pt->post_id = $post_id;
                $pt->tag_id = $new_tag->id;
                $pt->save();
            }
        }


   }
```

Im trying to echo the the title along with the tags, right after the commented place, but it fails to provide the correct output. I was wondering if Im using the correct way or my workaround is completely wrong.

Im using this code in the commented part:

```
$tweet = $post_item->title . ' tags: ' . $post_item->tags;
```

After doing some tests, I realized that if I use

```
var_dump($tag);
```

right after

```
foreach ($tags as $tag)
```

at my **createTags function**, it seems that all tags are output correctly.

Im wondering if I can store all $tags inside the createTag function's foreach, under a globally accessed variable that would be used in the initial handle function echoed.

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: Your `createTags` function is not returning anything that's why you don't get any output.

Comment: @rkg it actually does echo the proper tags, if I include an echo command after foreach $tags as $tag.

Comment: @PrashantDeshmukh..... Im not getting an error. I want to echo each $tag created in createTags function.

Comment: What `echo` command you are using that works correctly?

Comment: @PrashantDeshmukh..... My initial command returns nothing, but if I set an echo right after foreach ($tags as $tag) inside the createTags function, it outputs the tags correctly. Im wondering if I can store all $tags inside the createTag function's foreach, under a globally accessed variable that would be used in the initial handle function echoed.

Comment: Then you can put that `tags` in variable in `createTags` function and return at the end of of `createTags` function. and change this line `$this->createTags($item['categories'], $post_item->id);` to this `echo $this->createTags($item['categories'], $post_item->id);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing the post item model has a relation "tags" you could try this:

```
$tweet = $post_item->title . ' tags: ' . implode(', ', $post_item->tags->toArray());
```

Also if you would just like to echo the tags on the commented place, try this:

```
echo implode(',', $item['categories']);
```

Comment: Great - thats what I was looking for. I actually modified it to: 
$hashtags = '#' . implode( ' #', $item['categories'] ); so they appear as hashtags. Is there a way to trim whitespaces in categories that contain two words along with a whitespace in the middle?

Comment: Ended up in using preg_replace for this scope - Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome.
Not sure how your code looks right now but you could also use:
`array_map('trim', $item['categories']);`

Eventually change 'trim' into any function you desire.

Answer (score 0):

try if $post_item->tags - is array then

```
$tweet = $post_item->title . ' tags: ' . implode(', ', $post_item->tags);
```

if - collection then

```
$tweet = $post_item->title . ' tags: ' . $post_item->tags->join(', ');
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Tags are being generated from the createTags function I shared in the initial question.

Adding the array solution returns:  implode(): Invalid arguments passed

Comment: can you show output this code var_dump($post_item->tags);

Comment: It displays NULL - whereas the post has posts attached.

Comment: var_dump($tag) works fine, if I set an echo right after foreach ($tags as $tag) inside the createTags function tho

Comment: Im wondering if I can store all $tags inside the createTag function's foreach, under a globally accessed variable that would be used in the initial handle function echoed.